# Is there a MATLAB accumarray equivalent in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, accumulator

I'm looking for a fast solution to MATLAB's [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) in numpy. The `accumarray` accumulates the elements of an array which belong to the same index. An example:

```
a = np.arange(1,11)
# array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
accmap = np.array([0,1,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,1])
```

Result should be

```
array([13, 25, 17])
```

**What I've done so far:**
I've tried the `accum` function in the [recipe here](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/AccumarrayLike) which works fine but is slow.

```
accmap = np.repeat(np.arange(1000), 20)
a = np.random.randn(accmap.size)
%timeit accum(accmap, a, np.sum)
# 1 loops, best of 3: 293 ms per loop
```

Then I tried to use the [solution here](http://mldesign.net/blog/2013/02/18/speedy-numpy-replacement-for-matlab-accumarray/) which is supposed to work faster but it doesn't work correctly:

```
accum_np(accmap, a)
# array([  1.,   2.,  12.,  13.,  17.,  10.])
```

Is there a built-in numpy function that can do accumulation like this? Or any other recommendations?

Comment: My blog post is oudated. Try the github version. it has a well covering test suite.

Comment: @Michael and I have created a package called [`numpy-groupies`](http://github.com/ml31415/numpy-groupies) which includes an accumarray-like function called `aggregate`.  See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) with the `weights` optional argument. In your example you would do:

```
np.bincount(accmap, weights=a)
```

Answer (score 9):

Late to the party, but...

As @Jamie says, for the case of summing, `np.bincount` is fast and simple. However in the more general case, for other `ufuncs` such as `maximum`, you can use the [`np.ufunc.at`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) method.

I've put together <s>[a gist](https://gist.github.com/d1manson/5f78561c0f52d3073fe8)</s>[see link below instead] which encapsulates this in a Matlab-like interface.  It also takes advantage of the repeated indexing rules to provide a `'last'` and `'first'` function, and unlike Matlab, `'mean'` is sensibly optimized (calling `accumarray` with `@mean` in Matlab is really slow because it runs a non-builtin function for every single group, which is stupid).

Be warned that I haven't particularly tested the gist, but will hopefully update it in future with extra features and bugfixes.

**Update May/June-2015:** I have reworked my implementation - it is now available as part of [ml31415/numpy-groupies](https://github.com/ml31415/numpy-groupies/) and available on PyPi (`pip install numpy-groupies`). Benchmarks are as follows (see github repo for up-to-date values)...

```
function  pure-py  np-grouploop   np-ufuncat np-optimised    pandas        ratio
     std  1737.8ms       171.8ms     no-impl       7.0ms    no-impl   247.1: 24.4:  -  : 1.0 :  -  
     all  1280.8ms        62.2ms      41.8ms       6.6ms    550.7ms   193.5: 9.4 : 6.3 : 1.0 : 83.2
     min  1358.7ms        59.6ms      42.6ms      42.7ms     24.5ms    55.4: 2.4 : 1.7 : 1.7 : 1.0 
     max  1538.3ms        55.9ms      38.8ms      37.5ms     18.8ms    81.9: 3.0 : 2.1 : 2.0 : 1.0 
     sum  1532.8ms        62.6ms      40.6ms       1.9ms     20.4ms   808.5: 33.0: 21.4: 1.0 : 10.7
     var  1756.8ms       146.2ms     no-impl       6.3ms    no-impl   279.1: 23.2:  -  : 1.0 :  -  
    prod  1448.8ms        55.2ms      39.9ms      38.7ms     20.2ms    71.7: 2.7 : 2.0 : 1.9 : 1.0 
     any  1399.5ms        69.1ms      41.1ms       5.7ms    558.8ms   246.2: 12.2: 7.2 : 1.0 : 98.3
    mean  1321.3ms        88.3ms     no-impl       4.0ms     20.9ms   327.6: 21.9:  -  : 1.0 : 5.2 
Python 2.7.9, Numpy 1.9.2, Win7 Core i7.
```

Here we are using `100,000` indices uniformly picked from `[0, 1000)`. Specifically, about 25% of the values are `0` (for use with bool operations), the remainder are uniformly distribuited on `[-50,25)`. Timings are shown for 10 repeats.

- *purepy* - uses nothing but pure python, relying partly on `itertools.groupby`.
- *np-grouploop* - uses `numpy` to sort values based on `idx`, then uses `split` to create separate arrays, and then loops over these arrays, running the relevant `numpy` function for each array.
- *np-ufuncat* - uses the `numpy` `ufunc.at` method, which is slower than it ought to be - as disuccsed in [an issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5922) I created on numpy's github repo.
- *np-optimisied* - uses custom `numpy` indexing/other tricks to beat the above two implementations (except for `min max prod` which rely on `ufunc.at`).
- *pandas* - `pd.DataFrame({'idx':idx, 'vals':vals}).groupby('idx').sum()` etc.

Note that some of the `no-impl`s may be unwarranted, but I haven't bothered to get them working yet.

As explained on github, `accumarray` now supports `nan`-prefixed functions (e.g. `nansum`) as well as, `sort`, `rsort`, and `array`.  It also works with multidimensional indexing.

Comment: nice work guys. I am trying to use your routine. Sadly I canßt reproduce the same results as matlab, and also with a multidimensional array it is complicated to understand how it works. Can you help me a bit?

Comment: probably best to post a bug report on the github repo (providing a minimal code example would help)

Comment: thx for the answer. I'll make a question calling numpy groupies aggregate

Answer (score 4):

I've written an accumarray implementation with `scipy.weave` and uploaded it at github: https://github.com/ml31415/numpy-groupies

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with pandas DataFrame in one line.

```
In [159]: df = pd.DataFrame({"y":np.arange(1,11),"x":[0,1,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,1]})

In [160]: df
Out[160]: 
   x   y
0  0   1
1  1   2
2  0   3
3  0   4
4  0   5
5  1   6
6  1   7
7  2   8
8  2   9
9  1  10

In [161]: pd.pivot_table(df,values='y',index='x',aggfunc=sum)
Out[161]: 
    y
x    
0  13
1  25
2  17
```

You can tell the `pivot_table` to use specific columns as indices and values, and get a new DataFrame object. When you specify the aggregation function as the sum the results will be identical to Matlab's accumarray.

Answer (score 1):

Not as good as the accepted answer but:

```
[np.sum([a[x] for x in y]) for y in [list(np.where(accmap==z)) for z in np.unique(accmap).tolist()]]
```

This takes `108us per loop` (100000 loops, best of 3)

The accepted answer (`np.bincount(accmap, weights=a`) takes `2.05us per loop` (100000 loops, best of 3)

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
import numpy

def accumarray(a, accmap):

    ordered_indices = numpy.argsort(accmap)

    ordered_accmap = accmap[ordered_indices]

    _, sum_indices = numpy.unique(ordered_accmap, return_index=True)

    cumulative_sum = numpy.cumsum(a[ordered_indices])[sum_indices-1]

    result = numpy.empty(len(sum_indices), dtype=a.dtype)
    result[:-1] = cumulative_sum[1:]
    result[-1] = cumulative_sum[0]

    result[1:] = result[1:] - cumulative_sum[1:]

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly you are trying to do, but numpy unique has a bunch of optional outputs that you can use to accumulate. If your array has several identical values, then unique will count how many of the identical values there are by setting the return_counts option to true. In some easy applications, this is all that you need to do.

```
numpy.unique(ar, return_index=False, return_inverse=False, return_counts=True, axis=None)
```

You can also set the index to true and use it to accumulate a different array.