# count rows (vectors) corresponding to a specific row in a 2D np.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an `np.array` which is essentially an image in RGB format. I reshaped it to be more easy to work with. So, its shape is something like: `(22618, 3)` with each row corresponding to a pixel. I want to check if there are some pixels that correspond to a specific color(s) and also how many of them are of this color(s).

Let's say colors are `(0, 255, 255)` and `(255, 0, 0)` defined in a tuple. Also the np.array that contains the data is `data` (truly original!).

When I try:

```
any(data[(data2 == colors[0])])
```

it works as expected. If there are any pixels (triplets) corresponding to triplet of `colors[0]` it returns `True` otherwise `False`.
But when I try something like:

```
np.sum(data[(data == colors[1])])
```

the result is summing up all pixel values (R+G+B) of each pixel found to contain the same color.

I used just the array containing the boolean values (`data == colors[1]`) with little success. Also, I tried summing to a specific axis does not help that much:

```
np.sum(data == colors[1], axis=0)
```

> array([  373, 22618, 22618])

I could do some tricky maths here knowing that at most `373` pixels could be of the correct color but it's not precise calculation. I could use some functionality like `bincount` in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201972/can-numpy-bincount-work-with-2d-arrays) but the results seem to need extra work and also some experiments did not show to work as expected.

So, how do I count the number of pixels that have the same color? Any ideas?

Comment: How about `np.count_nonzero(np.all(data == colors[i], axis=1))`?

Comment: @PaulPanzer This should be an answer...

Comment: @liliscent If you say so ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want all elements of a given row to match your template color, so you should use `np.all` row-wise, that is along `axis` 1. This will result in a boolean array with one truth value for each row.

All that's left to do is count them:

```
np.count_nonzero(np.all(data == colors[i], axis=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this data:

```
data = np.array([(0,0,255),(0,0,255),(0,255,0),(0,0,0)])
```

and we're looking for this colour:

```
colour = (0,0,255)
```

Count how many tuples are matching:

```
match = [(x == colour).all() for x in data]
```

Your answer:

```
print(np.sum(match))
```

One-liner:

```
print(np.sum([(x == colour).all() for x in data]))
```

(If I got your question right)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in many colors, it would be more efficient to do something along these lines:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
unique_colors, counts = npi.count(npi.intersection(data, colors))
```

This will efficiently compute the counts for all colors of interest. (Disclaimer: I am the author of the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package).