# Can I parallelize `numpy.bincount` using `xarray.apply_ufunc`?

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I want to parallelize the `numpy.bincount` function using the `apply_ufunc` API of `xarray` and the following code is what I've tried:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
da = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(2,16,32),
                  dims=['time', 'y', 'x'],
                  coords={'time': np.array(['2019-04-18', '2019-04-19'],
                                          dtype='datetime64'), 
                         'y': np.arange(16), 'x': np.arange(32)})

f = xr.DataArray(da.data.reshape((2,512)),dims=['time','idx'])
x = da.x.values
y = da.y.values
r = np.sqrt(x[np.newaxis,:]**2 + y[:,np.newaxis]**2)
nbins = 4
if x.max() > y.max():
    ri = np.linspace(0., y.max(), nbins)
else:
    ri = np.linspace(0., x.max(), nbins)

ridx = np.digitize(np.ravel(r), ri)

func = lambda a, b: np.bincount(a, weights=b)
xr.apply_ufunc(func, xr.DataArray(ridx,dims=['idx']), f)
```

but I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-203-974a8f0a89e8> in <module>()
     12 
     13 func = lambda a, b: np.bincount(a, weights=b)
---> 14 xr.apply_ufunc(func, xr.DataArray(ridx,dims=['idx']), f)

~/anaconda/envs/uptodate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/computation.py in apply_ufunc(func, *args, **kwargs)
    979                                      signature=signature,
    980                                      join=join,
--> 981                                      exclude_dims=exclude_dims)
    982     elif any(isinstance(a, Variable) for a in args):
    983         return variables_ufunc(*args)

~/anaconda/envs/uptodate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/computation.py in apply_dataarray_ufunc(func, *args, **kwargs)
    208 
    209     data_vars = [getattr(a, 'variable', a) for a in args]
--> 210     result_var = func(*data_vars)
    211 
    212     if signature.num_outputs > 1:

~/anaconda/envs/uptodate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/computation.py in apply_variable_ufunc(func, *args, **kwargs)
    558             raise ValueError('unknown setting for dask array handling in '
    559                              'apply_ufunc: {}'.format(dask))
--> 560     result_data = func(*input_data)
    561 
    562     if signature.num_outputs == 1:

<ipython-input-203-974a8f0a89e8> in <lambda>(a, b)
     11 ridx = np.digitize(np.ravel(r), ri)
     12 
---> 13 func = lambda a, b: np.bincount(a, weights=b)
     14 xr.apply_ufunc(func, xr.DataArray(ridx,dims=['idx']), f)

ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

I am kind of lost where the error is stemming from and help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: `np.bincount(np.arange(10).reshape(2,5))` produces the same error. `a` is supposed to be a 1d array.  Any shape 2d will produce this error.  I'm not familiar with `apply_ufunc`, but `bincount` is not a `ufunc`.

Comment: Right, that's why I want to parallelize `bincount` for multidimensional arrays.

Comment: I'm also aware of `numpy.apply_along_axis()` as a possible solution but I was wondering if there's a `dask` friendly solution to this.

Comment: Why `apply_along_axis`?  There's nothing magical about that function. It just iterates over the other axes, passing a 1d array, one at a time, to your function.

Comment: Because it's one way to avoid a `for` loop?

Comment: When provided the `weights` argument, `apply_along_axis` also seems to fail, i.e. `np.apply_along_axis(np.bincount, -1, xr.DataArray(np.tile(ridx,(2,1)),dims=['time','idx']).data, weights=f.data)`... It "works" without the `weights` argument in a sense that it gives no errors but it's not the calculation I want.

Comment: Take some time to look at the `apply_along_axis` before you invest much into making it work.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `apply_along_axis` iterates over 1D slices of the first argument to the applied function and not any of the others.  If I understand your use-case correctly, you actually want to iterate over 1D slices of the weights [(`weights` in the `np.bincount` signature)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html), *not* the integer array (`x` in the `np.bincount` signature).

One way to work around this is to write a thin wrapper function around `np.bincount` that simply switches the order of the arguments:

```py
def wrapped_bincount(weights, x):
    return np.bincount(x, weights=weights)
```

We can then use `np.apply_along_axis` with this function for your use-case:

```py
def apply_bincount_along_axis(x, weights, axis=-1):
    return np.apply_along_axis(wrapped_bincount, axis, weights, x)
```

Finally, we can wrap this new function for use with xarray using [`apply_ufunc`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.apply_ufunc.html), noting that it can be automatically parallelized with dask (also note that that we do not need to provide an `axis` argument, because xarray will automatically move the input core dimension `dim` to the last position in the `weights` array before applying the function):

```py
def xbincount(x, weights):
    if len(x.dims) != 1:
        raise ValueError('x must be one-dimensional')

    dim, = x.dims
    nbins = x.max() + 1

    return xr.apply_ufunc(apply_bincount_along_axis, x, weights, 
        input_core_dims=[[dim], [dim]],
        output_core_dims=[['bin']], dask='parallelized',
        output_dtypes=[np.float], output_sizes={'bin': nbins})
```

Applying this function to your example then looks like:

```py
xbincount(ridx, f)

<xarray.DataArray (time: 2, bin: 5)>
array([[  0.      ,   7.934821,  34.066872,  51.118065, 152.769169],
       [  0.      ,  11.692989,  33.262936,  44.993856, 157.642972]])
Dimensions without coordinates: time, bin
```

As desired it also works with dask arrays:

```py
xbincount(ridx, f.chunk({'time': 1}))

<xarray.DataArray (time: 2, bin: 5)>
dask.array<shape=(2, 5), dtype=float64, chunksize=(1, 5)>
Dimensions without coordinates: time, bin
```

Comment: FYI this is what we are basically packaging in xhistogram: https://xhistogram.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't realize you had already solved this problem :). You're welcome to post an alternative answer. It looks like you've [taken a different approach internally](https://github.com/xgcm/xhistogram/blob/5d75f1b56b50455ae704886d5a4a02e0d45da66e/xhistogram/core.py#L21-L53). 
It's probably faster than what I have here.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late, but here is an alternative for computing bincount with multiple sets of weights. Please refer to @spencerkclark's answer for information about parallelizing the function.

There is a WARNING before using this: the function `bincount_2d_SLOW` is used to demonstrate the idea! Do not use this function in your code directly, it is very slow!

I will explain at the end why the idea of the function can greatly speed up your code relative to the solution posted by @spencerkclark, but only if you are computing the bincount multiple times using the same set of groups.

The idea of the code is that while we can't use `np.bincount` with 2d weights, we can convert 2d weights into 1d data that is directly usable by `np.bincount`.

The way we do this is:

1. we repeat our grouping column by the 2nd dimension of the weights, so the grouping and weights have the same shape.
2. we adjust the grouping values along the 2nd dimension, so that each set of weights has its own unique grouping values. This way, we are grouping along each set of weights separately.
3. We flatten the data, so it's 1d. Now we can run `np.bincount`.
4. Finally, reshape the data.

```py
def bincount_2d_SLOW(x, weights=None):
    if weights is None:
        return np.bincount(x)
    if len(weights.shape) == 1:
        return np.bincount(x, weights=weights)

    n_groups = x.max() + 1
    n_dims = weights.shape[1]

    # Expand x to the same number of dimensions as weights
    repeated_x = np.tile(x, (n_dims, 1)).T
    # Take Kronecker product, so bincount works separately along each dimension
    repeated_x = repeated_x + n_groups * np.arange(n_dims)
    # Flatten
    repeated_x = repeated_x.flatten()

    # Compute bincount
    return np.bincount(repeated_x, weights=weights.flatten()).reshape((n_dims, n_groups)).T
```

Here is why the idea of this function can speed up your code: if you are computing the bincount many times using the same set of groups, you can pre-compute the tiled-and-flattened groupings, and suddenly the code is incredibly fast. Here is an alternative function (I also added an option to specify `n_groups`, which can speed up the code even more):

```py
def bincount_2d(x, weights=None, n_groups=None):
    if weights is None:
        return np.bincount(x)
    if len(weights.shape) == 1:
        return np.bincount(x, weights=weights)

    n_dims = weights.shape[1]
    if n_groups is None:
        n_groups = (x.max() + 1) // n_dims

    return np.bincount(x, weights=weights.flatten()).reshape((n_dims, n_groups)).T
```

In some testing I did, `bincount_2d_SLOW` is about 1/3 slower than `apply_bincount_along_axis`. But `bincount_2d` was about 2x faster than `apply_bincount_along_axis` when I didn't specify `n_groups`, and when I did specify `n_groups`, it was about 3x faster.