# How to use python accum function with 3d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matlab, accumarray

I recently try to transfer some function from matlab to python. A function in matlab called "accumarray", `accumarray(3d_array(10*10*10),1)`, the output is also 10*10*10 3d array.

But when I try to do the same in "accum" function in python, I can not write directly "1" as a vals in the "accum(3d_array(10*10*10), vals)", do you know how can I make this function work, and output also the 3D array?

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Don't 'translate' between languages by simply looking up similar names.  At least read the respective function docs.

Comment: What python `accum` are you trying to use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856470/is-there-a-matlab-accumarray-equivalent-in-numpy